# While learning to use Python sqlite3 I get error "sqlite3.OperationalError: 2 values for 1 columns"

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite

I am learning python and have an assignment to parse a directory for all .txt file types.

I don't have an issue with that, but part two requires that they get put into a table in a dB and then printed to the console using `SQL Select` statements. I'm stuck on part two and I'm getting the error :

**"sqlite3.OperationalError: 2 values for 1 columns"**

This is what I have so far:

```
import sqlite3
import os

conn = sqlite3.connect('files.db')

with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_files( \
                ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, \
                col_files TEXT)')
    conn.commit()
conn.close()

conn = sqlite3.connect('files.db')

with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    file_ = [f for f in os.listdir('/Users/Scott/Desktop/fileList')
                  if f.endswith('.txt')]
    print(file_)
    cur.executemany('INSERT INTO tbl_files(col_files) VALUES (?, ?);', [file_])
    conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

This is my first question on Stack Overflow and I very much appreciate the help! Btw, I'm just using IDLE for now to follow along with the instructors lesson. I'm sure doing this in PyCharm would yield similar results. It's not the instrument, it's the musician type of thing. Thanks again.

Comment: Instead of ``VALUES (?, ?)`` only use ``VALUES (?)`` - your table only has one coulmn after all. Filling it multiple times is done with ``executemany`` as you've already figured out.

Comment: I see, so the number of columns dictates the number of ```?``` not the number of items your trying to pass in. Once you are passing in a sequence as you mentioned below, or one than 1 input, that's where executemany() comes into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your code.

- First, you're using two question marks `(?, ?)` for one parameter. It should be one.
- Second, `file_` is a list, and not a list of tuples as it should be. Meaning, `file_` would be 
  `['file.txt', 'my_file.txt', 'tt.txt', 'word.txt', 'data.txt']`
  While `executemany` requires
  `[('file.txt',), ('my_file.txt',), ('tt.txt',), ('word.txt',), ('data.txt',)]`
  The documentation of [executemany](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) states that it "executes an SQL command against all parameter sequences ... found in the (second argument)". Meaning the second argument to `executemany` should be a list or lists, list of tuples, etc.

The correct line is:

```
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO tbl_files(col_files) VALUES (?);', [(f,) for f in file_])
```

Comment: Any sequence type is fine, be it a list of list, a tuple of tuple, a tuple of list or a list of tuple. It may even be an [itertator](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany)

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much. Just trying to wrap my head around the second part- so when execute(), or executemany() is used to pass an argument with the 'string' type it needs to be a list of tuples? The [ ] in your answer create the list and the ( ) create the tuple(s) inside it? And I guess a follow-up would be is this true for all data types? Thanks again!

Comment: @MikeScotty So if I wrote ```([f,] for f in file_)``` which is the opposite,a tuple of lists, that would work too? So what it needs is any sequence inside a list, or tuple- whether it be a tuple or list? I know I'm just re-wording it, but for some reason if that's true it's clicking better for me.

Comment: Added some clarifying text to the answer. Have a look.

Comment: @Roy2012 Thank you, makes much more sense now.